# Advantages/Disadvantages of installing from source code

Tags: install-from-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to compile from source or to install from a .deb package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102391/is-it-better-to-compile-from-source-or-to-install-from-a-deb-package)

I've just installed conky from a source code, the advantage that I see is that I have the newest version (1.9 instead of 1.8 from repo). The disadvantage - to uninstall I have to remove sth from /usr/ I think, but I'm not sure. Are there any other disadvantages/advantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i can say compiling from source is an unsupported method of installing software because it bypasses the Package Management System (**APT, USC**) completely.

Also it affects system Stability, could break other dependencies . Since Ubuntu Packagers makes sure its all round effectiveness and integration to current system remains intact , therefore installing from official Repositories is recommended.

Also for further reading , refer [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8719145) and [this](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/23383.aspx).

Comment: I marked it as an answer, cause it is basically what I was looking for. But sometimes (like in conky example) official repositories just aren't enough.

Comment: Glad that it helped , for conky i mostly depend on this [Link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/conky/) .

Answer (score 2):

When installing from source, it will typically install into /usr/local/ rather than /usr (so as not to install conflict with system libraries.  This is typically picked up first in paths, so what's in /usr/local/ will always be used first.  So if you upgrade and get a newer conky from Ubuntu, when you try to run it, it'll run the old one from /usr/local/ instead.  (This can get particularly confusing with libraries...)